# ALT + codes in USB barcode scanner get interpreted as characters

Tags: keyboard, scanner, encoding

I have a Zebra 2D barcode scanner connected to Ubuntu14.04. The scanner is set up as a keyboard emulator.

When it scans a 2D Barcode (QR code) it outputs the scanned string which contains a FNC1 delimiter. This is an ASCII 29 code also called a Group Separator. However, because the scanner is emulating a keyboard it outputs keyboard keycodes, not ASCII, and so the FNC delimiter is output as an <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> sequence. If I scan directly into a terminal window, the delimiter actually shows up in the scanner output as characters `029`, ie the control character is converted into its equivalent three digit ASCII code!

It also does this if I scan directly into an input box on my Qt C++ application.

BUT, it does not show the FNC1 control codes if I scan into Gedit.

Can anyone explain what's going on here and point me in the right direction to get get the correct ASCII control character to show up as a delimiter in my application?

Comment: I would suggest you to detect the **Alt** modifier in your Qt program and convert manually the codes into their corresponding characters.